# Confusing integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-a)^2e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}dx$$
I've tried setting $$u=x-a$$ but I get stuck after that...
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2e^{-\lambda u^2}du$$
I know that the answer should be $$\frac{1}{2\lambda} + a^2$$
[Solution Manual Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N74my.png)

Comment: do this by parts. You would have to apply integration by parts two times.

Comment: That's what I thought and I've redone it twice, but gotten a wrong answer. I'll try it again, i guess.

Comment: Are you sure you have your integral right? $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-a)^2 \exp[-\lambda (x-a)^2]dx = \sqrt{\pi}/(2\lambda^{3/2})$, not $1/(2\lambda) + a^2$. Also you forgot your $dx$ and $du$.

Comment: I've added an image of the solution

Comment: Except that the solution is a solution to a different integral.

Comment: The question in image is not the one you wrote. Is it on purpose ?

Comment: The solution given in the book seems to be wrong.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}\mathrm dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u+a)^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du\qquad (\text{putting }x-a=u, \,x=a+u,\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm du)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u^2+2au+a^2)\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du}_{I_1}+2a\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du}_{I_2}+a^2\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du}_{I_3}\\
&=I_1+2aI_2+a^2I_3
\end{align}
$$
$I_2=0$ because is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval.

$I_3=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$ is a known [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

For $I_1$ differentiating w.r.t $\lambda$ and integrating we have
$$\begin{align}
I_1=
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\left(u^{2}\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^{2}}\right)\,du=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\left(-\frac {\partial }{\partial \lambda}\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\right)\mathrm du=-\frac {\partial }{\partial \lambda}\underbrace{\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\mathrm e^{-\lambda u^2}\mathrm du}_{I_3=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}}=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}
\end{align}
$$
So we have 
$$
I=I_1+2aI_2+a^2I_3=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}+2a\cdot 0+a^2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}\left(\frac{1}{2\lambda}+a^2\right)
$$
The integral in your book is
$$
\mathcal I=A\cdot I=A\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}\left(\frac{1}{2\lambda}+a^2\right)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}+a^2
$$
if $A\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}=1$ that is $A=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Confused by the down vote here, I rather liked it, +1